# jQuery .prop('checked', true) don't work

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, input, preventdefault

I have a set of simple checkboxes, that can check multiple option, but I wish it to behave like a radio button where there will always be one option that is checked.

as you can see in my code, the checkbox will checked, and than uncheck.  please let me know what I did wrong. Thanks

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 1 && $(this).is(':checked')) {
    return false; 
                // there is only one checked AND the checked one is $this and we want to prevent it from uncheck
  } else {
   $(this).prop('checked', true);
   alert($(this).prop('checked')); // this return true
  } 

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
```

Comment: `if(cond){return false} return false`. Why not `return false` directly? And `return false` includes `preventDefault` in jQuery.

Comment: I try it your way before.. but it seem like it mess up with the math of length.. I can not be sure it will count the one currently checked or not... ???

Comment: Do you want *only* one item to be checked or *at least* one item to be checked?

Comment: at least one, thanks for everybody's help but it also need able to check multiple as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow multiple checks, but disallow zero checks, this code should suffice:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event) {
  if(!$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

`event.preventDefault()` makes your `.prop` not working

You'll also need to uncheck others when a checkbox is checked.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(event) {
  // Remove this line
  // event.preventDefault();
  
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length === 1) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      return false; // this is checked
    }
    return false; // and this is the only one check 
  } else {
    
    // Uncheck others
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    alert($(this).prop('checked')); // this return true
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault() makes your .prop not working` thanks.. I read the doc over and over... and couldn't find anything about this one... THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    this.checked = $('input:checked').length ? this.checked : true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' checked/>
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasn't clear I need at least one checked but two or more can be check as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the checked checkbox from being unchecked:

```js
var $checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  this.checked = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

If you want to be able to uncheck the checked one:

```js
var $checkbox = $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
  $checkbox.not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily answers OP's question, but it might help some who come here as I did.

In my case I had multiple checkboxes checking witch input should be submited to the form but only two of them are such that at least one of them must be checked. Using jQuery 1.11 as well.

**EDIT 1:** 2019-12-10

Added code to change the `checked="checked"` attribute as well.

**EDIT 2:** 2019-12-11

Added code to change the `value="1"` or `value="0"` attribute as well.

```js
var checkbox_phone = $('.checkbox label[for="tel"] input')
var checkbox_email = $('.checkbox label[for="email"] input')
checkbox_phone.change(function() {
    var set_to_true = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
    if (set_to_true == 'true') {
        checkbox_phone.attr('checked', 'checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_phone.attr('value', '1'); // EDIT 2
    } else {
        checkbox_phone.removeAttr('checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_phone.attr('value', '0'); // EDIT 2
        checkbox_email.prop('checked', true);
        checkbox_email.attr('checked', 'checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_email.attr('value', '1'); // EDIT 2
    }
});
checkbox_email.change(function() {
    var set_to_true = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'true' : 'false';
    if (set_to_true == 'true') {
        checkbox_email.attr('checked', 'checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_email.attr('value', '1'); // EDIT 2
    } else {
        checkbox_email.removeAttr('checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_email.attr('value', '0'); // EDIT 2
        checkbox_phone.prop('checked', true);
        checkbox_phone.attr('checked', 'checked'); // EDIT 1
        checkbox_phone.attr('value', '1'); // EDIT 2
    }
});
```

```html
...
<!-- Phone number -->
<div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="tel">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Phone</strong>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" autocomplete="tel" type="text" placeholder="Enter your phone number" >
</div>
<!-- E-mail -->
<div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="email">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Email</strong>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter you email address">
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that works very well and never Fails

```
$("#target1").removeAttr('checked'); // Remove checked property 
$("#target2").attr('checked','checked'); // Add checked Property
```

I hope this will help .